# Updating state on specific state object using dynamic form handling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically accept state changes from a medium sized form without "hard coding" each input's name. The problem is my state has varying categories, for example:

```
this.state = {
  data: {

    account: {
      email: "",
      username: ""
    },

    bio: {
      location: "",
      bio: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Parent's render of child:

```
return <Child onChange={this.handleBioChange} info={this.state.data.bio} />
```

I have created an onChange prop for the child component that calls a method of the child

```
<input 
  value={this.props.info.location.value} 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
  name="bio.location" 
/>
```

My Child component's change handler is like so

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.props.onChange(event)
}
```

I am not too sure about what to do with the Parent component's state update function.

I will have two handlers, one for "account" and one for "bio" because they will use different validations so I am separating them but for the sake of this example I am only trying to update the `bio` state.

I have tried:

```
handleBioChange(event){
  let name = event.target.name
  let value = event.target.value

  this.setState([name]: value)
}
```

but when I do this, the state is not being updated and thus not allowing me to change the value of the input. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

setState work as below

**for simple variables:**

```
handleBioChange(event){
    let name = event.target.name
    let value = event.target.value

    //   this.setState([name]: value)

    this.setState({ location: name, bio: value }) // if location and bio are normal var
}
```

not sure for your logical part, what is bio and location. But to assign value to state

```
this.setState({name : value})
```

syntax is used, where `name` is state variable name and `value` that we want to assign to it.

**for object:**

```
handleBioChange(event){
    let name = event.target.name
    let value = event.target.value

    const bioLocation = this.state.bio; // get bio object
    bioLocation.location = name; // assign values
    bioLocation.bio = value; // assign values
    this.setState({bio: bioLocation}); // update object
}
```